# softlinks on a shared mount mean different things

Tags: linux, centos

Two centos servers having a drive mount shared between them.

If there is a softlink inside of that shared mount, pointing to any other location outside the mount, the mount is normally resolved relative to the server you are on.

ln -s /mounted/dir1 dir1
on server 1 this routes to server1/dir1
on server 2 this routes to server2/dir1

There can be two completely different contents at this location depending on if you ssh to server1 or server 2.

What would be the path to make the contents of server2:dir1 resolve to that position regardless of server, short of literally moving that directory into the mounted location?  Is there a different way to connect that folder into the mount?  I am thinking NO there is no way to link out beyond the shared mount point.  Is there an alternative i need to know about.  Would a bind command inside of the shared mount cross this barrier?